# How to format such string?

Tags: python, django

I have a template to render but since it has some tags too it's getting difficult to access particular strings.The code goes like this:

```
   template="""
   <select>
   <option {% if record.views = '%s' %} selected {% endif %}>'%s'
   </select>
   """%(pop, pop)
```

Here I want the value of pop but it gives an error that:

```
    Caught TypeError while rendering: not enough arguments for format string
```

Any solution how can i access those string format.
Thanks

Comment: I *think* your main problem is that you are templating your template....a little bit unorthodox. Any chance you could do this someother way or use the templating language to do what you're trying?

Comment: For reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double the % signs:

```
template="""
   <select>
   <option {%% if record.views = '%s' %%} selected {%% endif %%}>'%s'
   </select>
   """%(pop, pop)
```

yields

```
<select>
<option {% if record.views = '1' %} selected {% endif %}>'1'
</select>
```

for pop='1'

Answer (score 4):

Seriously, don't try to preprocess the template language. It's a template language! It deals with this sort of thing!

Send `selected_type` into the template context, and do:

```
<option {% if record.views = selected_type %} selected {% endif %}>'{{ selected_type }}'
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should just double up the "%" to escape them

```
template="""
   <select>
   <option {%% if record.views = '%s' %%} selected {%% endif %%}>'%s'
   </select>
   """%(pop, pop)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because Python is looking to fill all four of the `%` symbols. You need to escape them, by adding another `%` in front of them, like so:

```
template="""
   <select>
   <option {%% if record.views = '%s' %%} selected {%% endif %%}>'%s'
   </select>
   """%(pop, pop)
```